# concurrent .net web api service calls returning duplicate data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-web-api

**The setup**

We have a web app hosted on IIS 7.5 that uses a .net web api rest service to short-poll a SQL Server 2008 database.  The service controller calls a stored procedure to read the data.

**The problem**

When concurrent requests are made to the same web service, we intermittently see the duplicate results, and sometime other processes results, returned to the browser.

**C# service code**

```
namespace ImageApp_REST_Services.Repositories {
public class ImageLinkRepository : IImageLinkRepository
{

    private List<ImageLink> ImageLinks
    {
        get;
        set;

    }

    public IEnumerable<ImageLink> Get(String userId)
    {

        ImageLinks = new List<ImageLink>();

        using (var cnnSQL = new SqlConnection(...))
        {

            // opend connection to DB
            cnnSQL.Open();

            try
            {

                SqlCommand cmmSQL = new SqlCommand("nVision_select_lcimagelinks_sp", cnnSQL);
                cmmSQL.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter prmSQL = cmmSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@LCIMGLINKUSERID",
                    Value = userId
                });

                SqlDataReader rdrSQL = cmmSQL.ExecuteReader();

                if (rdrSQL.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rdrSQL.Read())
                    {

                        ImageLinks.Add(new ImageLink
                        {
                            // set new ImageLink object's properties    
                            imageTopicId = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKIMGTOPICID"),
                            id = DBReader.SQLInt(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKPK"),
                            recordId = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKRECORDID"),
                            text = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKTEXT"),
                            topicId = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKTOPICID"),
                            topicItem = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKTOPICITEM"),
                            url = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKURL"),
                            user = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKUSERID")
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }

        return ImageLinks;
    }



}
```

}

Again, when multiple requests are hitting the service simultaneously, we occasionally see either duplicate records returned, or records belonging to another service call.

We want the service to only return the data for the given request.  Does anyone know what is wrong???

Comment: `ImageLinks` should be a local variable

Comment: @JohnSaunders  Why does defining `ImageLinks` inside the Get method seem to fix the problem, or, why does having it defined at the class level cause the problem?

Comment: It is only used within the Get method, so does not need to be at the class level. Each Get call modifies it, and there's no need for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `ImageLinks` defined as a static member? If it is, the contents will be shared across multiple threads and web requests. One thread will overwrite the other's results. Long shot, but fits your issue.

Comment: Here is its definition: `private List<ImageLink> ImageLinks`

Comment: Are you using that elsewhere? Why not just a local variable? (My answer don't look like the solution but still wondering...)

Comment: At one time we thought we may use the same `List<ImageLinks>` for other methods inside the class.  Would defining it as static help?

Comment: You cannot use static members (fields or properties) within a web application. They will be shared across threads. You can use static methods. So no, don't define your variable as static.

Comment: You might try defining `ImageLinks` as a local variable.

Comment: I believe moving ImageLinks inside the Get method, like you said might have fixed the issue.  So far I'm running 4 simultaneous instances of the app, each are short polling the database every 7 seconds and I have yet to see the issue.  I'm going to keep testing to make sure.  Just so I know, why does moving the variable inside the Get method fix the problem?  Or, why does having  it defined at class level cause the problem?